# PHP Login Form - MySQL Database - Invalid Password

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, mariadb

I'm trying to login with this code, however I always get a negative when I try it ($errorMessage). I'm basicly trying to check the Username and Password to an existing database of *vanilla forums*. I got a User with only SELECT (read) access to the specific TABLE.
I don't get what exactly this line does:

> prepare("SELECT * FROM GDN_User WHERE Email = :Email")

I have these ROWS in my Database:

> UserID, Email, Password, (Name) (and more unrelevant ones)

```
<?php
//username-, password-vars (etc.) removed for stackoverflow post
//LOGIN START
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vanilla_forums', $username2, $password);
if(isset($_GET['Login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $passwort = $_POST['Passwort'];

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM GDN_User WHERE Email = :Email");
    $result = $statement->execute(array('Email' => $email));
    $user = $statement->fetch();

    //Überprüfung des Passworts
    if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['Passwort'])) {
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $user['UserID'];
        die('Login erfolgreich. Weiter zu <a href="access.php">internen Bereich</a>');
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "Password invalid.<br>";
    }
}

//LOGIN END
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login</title>    
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($errorMessage)) {
    echo $errorMessage;
}
?>

<form action="?Login=1" method="post">
E-Mail:<br>
<input type="email" size="40" maxlength="250" name="Email"><br><br>

Dein Passwort:<br>
<input type="password" size="40"  maxlength="250" name="Passwort"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Abschicken">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is possible that I simply did something wrong with Capped letters, however can't find the issue.

Comment: If your database column is named `Password`, this won't yield a result: `$user['Passwort']`

Comment: @Ruud my hero! this solved my issue. Thank you so much! Post it as an answer so i can give you best answer :)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile the Database is in english. I should stop mixing languages and as usually just stick to english.

Comment: Password in: $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vanilla_forums', $username2, $password); is database password and password_verify($passwort, $user['Passwort']) is user login password. I guess you missed to differenciate between those.

Comment: @frizzant yes stick to one language that will help you a lot to avoid silly mistakes as this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database column is named `Password`, this won't yield a result: `$user['Passwort']`.

I agree with your comment: stick with English. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add ':' in `execute()` function Email.

changed from:

```
    $result = $statement->execute(array('Email' => $email));
    $user=$statement->fetch();
```

To:

```
  $result = $statement->execute(array(':Email' => $email));
  $user=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```